# How to resolve error "Could not find a declaration file for module"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I build a @genepattern/nbtools locally and using this package in another package that I am trying to build but it shows this error while I am trying to import objects from nbtools.

```
yarn run v1.21.1
warning ../../package.json: No license field
$ tsc
src/index.ts:5:1 - error TS6133: 'basewidget' is declared but its value is never read.
5 import { basewidget } from '@mypackages/mypackage';
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/index.ts:5:23 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@mypackages/mypackage'. '/Users/usr1/Desktop/package/node_modules/@mypackages/mypackage/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/mypackages__mypackage` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@mypackages/mypackage';`
5 import { basewidget } from '@mypackages/mypackage';
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Found 2 errors.
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Didn't ```npm install @types/genepattern__nbtools``` help?

Comment: @FabioLopez I am installing @genepattern/nbtools from a local registry. the above command shows this error " Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fgenepattern__nbtools - Not found"